# Why is hibernate flush_before_completion always false when using JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am starting to convert a project from native hibernate to Spring Data JPA and I have found that some of my current hibernate code has stopped saving to the database. I have found that hibernate is not flushing before committing the transaction.

In my log I get the following on initialisation of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:

```
[org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl] - HHH000059: Defining hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
```

Why is this setting ignored with this JPA based setup?

How do I enable this functionality so that my legacy native hibernate code still works as it did before?

Comment: When using spring managed transactions the flush is taken care of for you. So unless you are destroying proper integration it should simply work.

Comment: Hi. It seems my config was causing the issue. But it was only configured slightly weirdly as I could not get the SessionFactory to be a part of the transaction (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/40505245/2199475). I configured it originally as per your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21673855/2199475. Any thoughts on that issue?

Comment: That was written quite a while ago... Could be that changes in hibernate (you didn't state the version of hibernate nor Spring btw) lead to that solution not working anymore. I believe it worked on Hibernate4, not sure if that still holds true for hibernate5. The only thing you would need is the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property and make sure you use the one appropriate for your Hibernate version.